# JavaScript for generate table row

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I have problem with JavaScript and HTML; I have a table with one row and I want use JavaScript to add an extra row. My script works fine, but my problem is that I want different ID for any `textbox`.

I am not familiar with JavaScript.

**at the end I want to insert my textbox data into MSSQL.**

My code:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var row = table.insertRow();

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        cell3.appendChild(element2);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        cell4.appendChild(element3);

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
        cell5.appendChild(element4);

        var cell6 = row.insertCell(4);
        var element5 = document.createElement("input");
        cell6.appendChild(element5);
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

and my html:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<table id="dataTable">
    <caption>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    </caption>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_relation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_age" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_education" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFam_statuse" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I appreciate suggestions on other scripts or other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.id = 'your_id';
cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

Comment: Can also be used in this way for the rest of the elements?

Comment: you can set the id property to all elements.

Comment: i try this code and generate table row , but i use script in my asp:panel ,  my problem is when i try hidden my panel , the row is gone !!